# Python figureCanvasTkAgg animation

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm using Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 17.10. This is an MVC that I tried to do for my actually long code.

I have to make an animated graph of the convolution of two signals, but when I graph, the screen turns gray and the graph just appears.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib import style
style.use("ggplot")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal as sn
import time

tim = np.arange(0,10)
tim1 = np.arange(0,10)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1280x700')
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
root.configure(bg = fondo)
root.title('Convolusión')

f2 = Figure(figsize=(3,2), dpi=100)
k2 = f2.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f2, root)
plot.show()
plot.get_tk_widget().place(x=50,y=470)
k3.clear()
ycc = sn.convolve(s1,s2,mode="full")
t = np.arange(min(tim)+min(tim1),max(tim)+max(tim1)+1)
i=0
tim = [0]*len(t)
y = [0]*len(t)
for x in t:
    tim[i] = t[i]
    y[i] = ycc[i]
    k3.clear()
    k3.plot(tim,y)
    plot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f3, self.root)
    plot.show()
    plot.get_tk_widget().place(x=450,y=470)
    i=i+1
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

Comment: As I told you yesterday [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49604712/python-tkinter-live-graph], you must use `matplotlib.animation`, with a function/method `animate` that updates the data, and returns it as a tuple, but does not attempt to display the plot...

Comment: It dosent work i already try it with matplotlib.animation i dont get any graph

Comment: Okay, then - good luck!

Comment: If the problem is that when using `FuncAnimation` you don't get any graph, the solution is for sure not to ask about some code which does not have `FuncAnimation` in it.

Comment: I made it already with pyplot.gcf().canvas.start_event_loop(0.001)